# How to break a Java time interval into DST subintervals

Tags: java, time, dst

Suppose I have a `TimeInterval` defined as

```
class TimeInterval {
    Date start;
    Date end;
}
```

I want an algorithm that will efficiently divide the TimeInterval into sub-TimeIntervals where each sub-TimeInterval is in a single Daylight Savings Time state for a given TimeZone.  i.e. a method of TimeInterval defined by `List<TimeInterval> getDstSubIntervals()`.

It seems that one can do this by iterating hour by hour from start to end time, and testing the DST offset at each hour, but that seems painfully slow.

Comment: Well, you won't know how slow your first kick at the can is until you give it a try.

Comment: In the accepted answer to the linked question, instead of `Instant.now()` use `start.toInstant()`. Better yet, don’t use the outdated `Date` class; instead declare `start` and `end` of type `Instant`. It’s the corresponding class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.